# GET/POST запросы Android

Tags: android, json, spring, post, get

Пишу простой тестовый клиент на Android, нужно отправлять post/get json - запросы на локальный сервер который написан на spring'e. Собственно вопрос - какую библиотеку вы посоветуете использовать для передачи json на локальный сервер.

Данные, которые хочу отправлять это логин/пароль, координаты местоположения.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны 2 варианта.

1. Использовать [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) - создано как раз для `REST`
2. Использовать [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) - входит в `Retrofit`